# RabbitMQ routing behavior

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm trying to publish message to 2 different queueus via RabbitMQ, but things do not behave as what I expected, here is the detail:

I have an exchange: amq.fanout, type: fanout, and the bindings are Queue: Q1, Routing key: key1, and Queue: Q2, Routing key: key2.

In my client side, I have this code

`var model = connection.CreateModel();
model.ExchangeDeclare("amq.fanout", "fanout", true);
model.BasicPublish("amq.fanout", "key1", null, body);`

I'm supposing to publish the body to Q1, because it has the key1 as the routing key, however, both Q1 and Q2 received the body, is there anything wrong with my code or server config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a fanout exchange will always deliver a message to every bound queue, no matter the routing key used or binding. the routing key is completely ignored in a fanout exchange.

what you're looking for is not a fanout exchange, based the description of your needs.

if you want to deliver a message to a specific queue based on the routing key used, you need to either use a direct exchange (for simple matching of routing keys) or a topic exchange (for complex, pattern matching of routing keys)